# How can I make a controller spec completely isolated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here's a spec I'm creating:

```
  describe 'POST create' do
    let!(:user){ mock_model(User).as_null_object}

    before do
      User.stub(:new).and_return "foobs"
    end

    it{}
  end
```

Now, the whole point of mocking is so your expectations are isolated, and so you know exactly where your application has gone wrong, and you don't get a knock on effect (like in an integration spec) where one erroneous method can cause a hundred specs to fail.

With that in  mind, if I don't touch my User model, the above empty expectation passes. If I mess up the contents of the User model, I get `ActiveRecord` errors, and if I delete the User model entirely I get this error:

```
 uninitialized constant UsersController::User
```

I thought the `mock_model` method (on line 2) would, you know, mock the model? How can I make the above spec completely isolated?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to use the `double` method.

```
  describe 'POST create' do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user }  
    before do
      User = double # the name of this variable could be anything. 
    end

    it "" do
        User.should_recieve(:new).with(user).and_return user
        User.should_recieve(:save).and_return true
        post :create
    end
  end
```

The double creates null object. You then run expectations on that object, rather than the actual model object. It can 'receive requests' for its methods just like any object, and we can mock those.

Please tell me if I'm doing it wrong!